# Ubuntu server: Trouble setting up Courier-IMAP server

Tags: ubuntu, imap, courier

I'm running Ubuntu server 11.10 and trying to set up an IMAP server with Courier-IMAP. I followed guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Courier which is basically nothing more than `apt-get install courier-imap`.

The problem comes when I try to test the server with `telnet 127.0.0.1 143`. Immediately get "Connection closed by foreign host." Complete output:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

`/var/log/mail.log` contains:

```
dovecot: master: Fatal: execv(/usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login) failed: No such file or directory
dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): child 7466 returned error 84 (exec() failed)
dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling
```

The binary `imap-login` does not exist in that directory, nor does `locate imap-login` show any output so it's safe to say that I do not have it on my system. Is `courier-imap` a broken package? Or am I missing a dependency? Keep in mind, this is my first venture into the world of mail servers, so I'm not very knowledgeable on the topic yet. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: After a little more investigation, I can install the package `dovecot-imapd` which provides `imap-login`, but apt forces me to remove `courier-imap` to install it. Then, if I try to install `courier-imap` and installing `dovecot-imapd` apt forces me to remove `dovecot-imapd` which removes `imap-login`. Something isn't right with the dependencies and conflicts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing the `dovecot-imapd` package, and copying `/usr/lib/dovecot/{imap-login,imap}` to my home dir and then uninstalled `dovecot-imapd`, installed `courier-imap` and copied the `imap-login` and `imap` binaries back into `/usr/lib/dovecot/`. Everything seems to be working, although I'm sure this will break in the future when courier is updated. Hopefully by then the package dependency/conflict problem will have been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by installing dovecot-core and restarting courier:

```
sudo apt-get install dovecot-core
sudo /etc/init.d/courier-imap restart
```